# In C# how do you make the columns in a DataGrid AutoFit Column Width like you can in Excel?

Tags: c#, datagrid

In C# how do you make the columns in a DataGrid AutoFit Column Width like you can in Excel? Currently my five columns are fixed width but the column headers can change so I would like the columns to autofit to the width of the column.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is about DataGrid (WPF), and the current existing answers are for DataGridView (WinForms), is that correct ?

Answer (score 7):

There's a property on the DataGridView called AutoSizeColumnsMode which is an enum. The available values are:

AllCells

AllCellsExceptHeader

ColumnHeader

DisplayedCells

DisplayedCellsExceptHeader

Fill

None

Answer (score 1):

To take BFree's answer a step further:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autoresizecolumns.aspx

Answer (score 1):

### **C# this is my function for add a DataGrid on your form with all fit Columns**

```
   public static DataGrid AddDataGrid(DataGrid DG, object Me, System.Data.DataTable DS)
    {


        try {
            DG.DataSource = DS;
            Me.Controls.Add(DG);
            DataGridTableStyle TblS = new DataGridTableStyle { MappingName = DS.TableName };
            DG.TableStyles.Clear();
            DG.TableStyles.Add(TblS);


            for (ColIndex = 0; ColIndex <= DS.Columns.Count - 1; ColIndex++) {
                int maxlength = 0;
                Graphics g = DG.CreateGraphics();

                // Take width of one blank space and add to the new width of the Column.
                int offset = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(g.MeasureString(" ", DG.Font).Width));

                int i = 0;
                int intaux = 0;
                string straux = null;
                int tot = DS.Rows.Count;

                for (i = 0; i <= (tot - 1); i++) {
                    straux = DS.Rows[i][ColIndex].ToString();
                    // Get the width of Current Field String according to the Font.
                    intaux = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(g.MeasureString(straux, DG.Font).Width));
                    if ((intaux > maxlength)) {
                        maxlength = intaux;
                    }
                }

                // Assign New Width to DataGrid column.
                DG.TableStyles(DS.TableName).GridColumnStyles(ColIndex).Width = maxlength + offset;

            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        } finally {
            DG.Show();
        }

        return DG;
    }
```

**a example for using this function...**

```
     private void AddDataGrid(DataSet Ds)
    {
        AddDataGrid(new DataGrid { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, this, Ds.Tables[0]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**VB this is my function for add a DataGrid on your form with all fit Columns**

```
Shared Function AddDataGrid(ByVal DG As DataGrid, ByVal This As Object, ByVal DS As System.Data.DataTable) As DataGrid

        Try

            DG.DataSource = DS
            This.Controls.Add(DG)
            Dim TblS As New DataGridTableStyle() With {.MappingName = DS.TableName}
            DG.TableStyles.Clear()
            DG.TableStyles.Add(TblS)

            For ColIndex = 0 To DS.Columns.Count - 1

                Dim maxlength As Integer = 0
                Dim g As Graphics = DG.CreateGraphics()

                ' Take width of one blank space and add to the new width of the Column.
                Dim offset As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(g.MeasureString(" ", DG.Font).Width))

                Dim i As Integer = 0
                Dim intaux As Integer
                Dim straux As String
                Dim tot As Integer = DS.Rows.Count

                For i = 0 To (tot - 1)
                    straux = DS.Rows(i)(ColIndex).ToString()
                    ' Get the width of Current Field String according to the Font.
                    intaux = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(g.MeasureString(straux, DG.Font).Width))
                    If (intaux > maxlength) Then
                        maxlength = intaux
                    End If
                Next

                ' Assign New Width to DataGrid column.
                DG.TableStyles(DS.TableName).GridColumnStyles(ColIndex).Width = maxlength + offset

            Next


        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Finally
            DG.Show()
        End Try

        Return DG
    End Function
```

**a example for using this function...**

```
Private Sub AddDataGrid(ByVal Ds As DataSet)

    AddDataGrid(New DataGrid With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}, Me, Ds.Tables(0))

End Sub
```